# Using python to code Ev3 windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, lego-mindstorms

I was going around the internett and i found out that you can code Mindstorm with python, however it was for Linux only and im running windows. Is there a way/website where i can learn how to connect python up to mindstorms and get sensor data?

Comment: why did i get downvoted? did i ask a bad question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EV3 brick itself runs Linux, so when you see that it is for "Linux only", this is most likely referring to the EV3.

The easiest way to use Python with the EV3 is with http://ev3dev.org. There are not any tutorials yet for absolute beginners.<sup>[1](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/492)</sup> However there should be enough information to get started. [ev3dev-lang-python](https://github.com/rhempel/ev3dev-lang-python) is the most up-to-date python library. You can also [search issues about python](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/search?q=python&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

You can write python files on Windows (it's just a text file) and copy them to the EV3 and run them. You can use [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) for copying files. There are a couple of things to watch out for though.<sup>[2](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/400#issuecomment-213521716)</sup>

1. Line endings: Windows uses CR/LF line endings and Linux uses LF. Be sure to use a text editor that support Unix file endings.
2. File permissions: Windows doesn't do POSIX file permissions. Both Filezilla and WinSCP have settings where you can change file permissions of remote files on the EV3. You have to check the "executable" bit in order to be able to run the file.